# Dispatcher.Invoke odd behavior with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, http, asynchronous, dispatcher

I'm developing application with C#, Net 4.5.2 and WPF. It has remotely controlled GUI, so incoming `HTTP GET` requests (handled with Nancy) trigger some changes in `Window`s. Since server isn't running in GUI thread, I'm using `Dispatcher.Invoke` to call graphic changing methods. And there I get really weird behavior: if `Show` was not called for my `Window`, nothing happens. But calling `Show` creates 2 windows instead of one. How can I fix it?

```
public partial class App : Application //App.xaml.cs
{
    public static MainWindow mainWindow;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        //REMOVING NEXT LINE COMPLETELY BREAKS DISPATCHER.INVOKE IN mainWindow
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}


public class MainModule : Nancy.NancyModule //Nancy server module
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/stop"] = param => App.mainWindow.StopContent();
    }
}


public partial class MainWindow : Window //WPF window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void StopContent()
    {
        //LINE BELOW WON'T WORK IF Show WASN'T CALLED
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { Background = null; }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I also [had problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22460116/1997232) with creating windows in `Startup`.  Second window is created probably because it's defined in `application.xaml` as `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`. And `Invoke` won't work until you have window (something what will process dispatcher queue). See [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6708765/1997232) how to overcome it.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks, removing `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` fixed double windows creation. But still, what's wrong with `Invoke` without `Show`?

Comment: If the window is not shown, what do you expect to happen if you set the background to null ?

Comment: @Lumo even without calling `Show()` it's shown.

Comment: But then you're using StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" right ? Otherwise there must be some other code that opens the window. I do exactly the same but it works.

Comment: Yes, exactly. With `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` window is shown, but `Invoke` do nothing.